# Remove JetInstance job

Tags: java, collections, hazelcast-jet

Is there a way, how I can remove not RUNNING jobs from my hazelcastInstance?

I have stream from `jetInstance.getJobs()` and I need to return `Map<String, Object>`, where key is the name of job. But it is not possible, since I already stopped and re-run some jobs - there are more instances with the same name.

I was not able to find any possible solution for my case except for removing finished ones.

I am not sure, if it is even possible. Thank you for some solution or hints.

Answer (score 0):

Job name is not required to be unique. If you need to distinguish jobs, use `Job.getId()`. Or, if you re-submit jobs, use different name. This is by design, name is just a tag, not an identifier.

Comment: Yes, I know. But job names are only thing I know. They are well known through app lifecycle. I am just trying not to change design. I will be probably forced to use multimap and iterate more...